# Keep browser window open while changing chrome options (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to change the proxy settings on a browser without restarting it for the settings to take effect. Is this possible, and if so, how?

EDIT: Figured out a solution that works for me, however, it's not doing what's in the question and still requires a lot more time to complete requests. (Stopping the browser whenever it encounters Cloudflare, swapping proxies, moving on, etc. Stuff I'd quite like to avoid, as this task is extremely time-sensitive and consistency reliant.)

Answer (score 0):

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://ip:ports')
    driver = Chrome(options=option)
    Login_page(driver).login()
```

I think no need to restart

Comment: You're redefining driver, so it does would need to restart the session to get a new proxy.